# More efficient method to sort read-in text file

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, methods

I've read in a text file to excel from a database and I've done it in such a way that it filters out unnecessary columns.  My approach to filter rows was to use two subroutines and call the 2nd from within the first.  It takes ~8 seconds for the sheet to be filtered and there is only 400 or so rows.  The fact that it takes that long (even though it works) is that my code is inefficient.  If anyone has a better method I would greatly appreciate the knowledge! To delimit rows I've used the following VBA:

```
Sub FilterAndDelete()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
Select Case Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 3)
    Case "CHA", "HAM", "BKN"
        Call FilterAndDeleteB
    Case Else
        Rows(i).Delete
        Call FilterAndDeleteB
End Select
Next i
End Sub

Sub FilterAndDeleteB()
Dim Br As Long, i As Long
Br = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = Br To 1 Step -1
Select Case Left(Range("B" & i).Value, 1)
    Case "-"
        Rows(i).Delete
    Case Else
        'do nothing
End Select
Next i
```

Comment: This might be better on codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Repeatedly reading the worksheet is **very** costly.  I would either use either auto-filter or advanced filter; if not fast enough, read the entire data table into an array (a single statement); collect the rows to be kept in a Collection or Dictionary object; fill a results array with the Collection; write the array back to the worksheet.  You will speed up the process probably by a factor of ten.

Comment: Good idea's both.  I'll shake both trees and see which yields fruit.  Much thanks!